# exception caught by flutter framework in testing flutter

Tags: flutter, testing

I'm writing test cases to test one screen in flutter and this project has firebase integration,

Here's my code for testing

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('splash_test', (WidgetTester tester) async {

    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
    expect(find.byType(SvgPicture), findsWidgets);
    await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  });
}
```

but I'm getting this error,

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FirebaseException was thrown running a test:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

so can anyone help me with this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't write normal text, not even titles, in all upper case. It's considered shouting, and it's very rude to shout at the people you want to help you.

Comment: I didn't knew that, Just changed the title.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  testWidgets('splash_test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
    await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    expect(find.byType(SvgPicture), findsWidgets);
    
  });
}
```